# Discrete-to-continuum convergence of principal Fokker-Planck eigenvalues

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, elliptic-pde, finite-differences

I am looking for a reference justifying the following statement.
Let $L^n$ be any "reasonably consistent" finite-difference approximation of the Fokker-Planck operator in dimension $d=1$
$$
Lu=-\partial_{xx} u +\partial_x(u\partial_x V),
\hspace{1cm}x\in (0,1)
$$
with Dirichlet boudary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$ and uniform mesh $x_i=i/n$, $i=0,\dots,n$.
(Here $V\in C^1([0,1];\mathbb R)$ is a prescribed, smooth potential.)

---

> Then the principal eigenvalue and eigenfunctions $\lambda^n_1\to \lambda_1$ and $(u^n_1)_{i=0,n}\to u_1(x)$ as $n\to \infty$.

---

Ideally I would need convergence of the eigenfunctions to hold in the "$C^1$ sense", i-e if $\overline u^n_1(x)$ denotes the natural piecewise affine interpolation of the discrete eigenvector $u^n_1$ then in fact $\overline u^n_1\to u_1$ in $W^{1,\infty}(0,1)$ (possibly stronger with a better interpolation? anyway, I need the first discrete derivative of $u^n_1$ to converge in any possible sense to the first derivative $\partial_x u_1$)

By "reasonably consistent approximation" I mean for example
$$
(L^nu)_i= -\frac{u_{i-1}-2u_i+u_{i+1}}{h^2} + \frac 1h\left[\alpha_i(u_{i+1}V'_{i+1}-u_iV'_i)+\beta_i (u_iV'_i-u_{i-1}V'_{i-1})\right]
$$
with $ V'_i := V'(i/N)$ and $h=1/n$ (and appropriate Dirichlet boundary conditions).
The coefficients $\alpha_i,\beta_i\in [0,2]$ are such that $\alpha_i+\beta_i\to 1$ uniformly in $i$ as $n\to\infty$, hence the second term is indeed a consistent approximation of the drift term $\partial_x (u\partial_x V)$.

When the potential $V\equiv 0$ it is a classical exercise to compute explicitly the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, see for example [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390708/convergence-of-discrete-laplacian-to-continuous-one). Of course when $V\not\equiv 0$ no epxlicit expression can be leveraged, but the result should be written somehere out there? Note that I am only interested in the **principal** eigenvalue, I am well aware that approximating higher order modes becomes increasingly more difficult.

I tried looking into a few numerical analysis textbooks, but could not find anywhere a corresponding statement.
I also asked a few colleagues, but I don't know too many people with expertise in this field so I decided to ask for helpe here on MO.

Comment: A sufficient condition is to use the characterization of the spectral gap as Rayleigh quotient (min of Dirichletform divided by variance, or constraint variance equal one) and prove a $\Gamma$-convergence statement for the Dirichlet form and check that the topology is strong enough to have strong convergence of the variance. This strategy provides a $\liminf$-estimate for the discrete to continuum eigenvalues. What is not completely clear to me: How does the variance (either as divisor or constraint) interplay with the $\Gamma$-convergence statement.

Comment: Once again, thanks André. I'm starting to feel that I keep writing questions just for you to answer. This looks promising indeed, I'll look deeper into it. Actually for my specific problem (more complicated, includes singular weights) I think it should work. At least now I have a clue on how to get started. Obrigado!